# Using regular expression to split these words

Tags: java, regex

How to get the info using regular expression  what I need.

***Example:***

```
gb_reg_test2-2I_114.dexl.gz, gb_bk_test1_P01-2I_114.dexl.gz, aa_bb_cc-2I_114.dexl.gz
```

***Expect:***

```
gb_reg_test2, gb_bk_test1, aa_bb_cc
```

***General Case:***

```
**-2I_114.dexl.gz, **_P01-2I_114.dexl.gz
```

Comments: '**' can be any words. Such as aa_bb, aa_vv_cc, aa_bbb_ccc_ddd_ee, aa.

What I need is '**'

I have spent hours on it, but still have no clue, will be appreciate someone can help me out.

Comment: Try [`gb_[^_]+_test\d`](https://regex101.com/r/B66iVP/1/)

Comment: thx for the comments. That expression is too specific. 'gb_reg_test2' can be any character. Such as aaa_bb_cc, aa_dd .... For these situations, your expression will not be worked.

Comment: so you say aa out of aa-2I is ok, aa out of aa_P01-2I is ok but P01 out of P01-2I isnt (now)? Please specify clearly what you need.

Comment: You know that these two scenarios overlap the way you have written them?  Why don't you have gb_bk_test1_P01 as a correct answer since it corresponds to the pattern **-2I_114.dexl.gz and ** can be any words. In this case how can I have the word WORD_P01?

Comment: these 2 scenarios indeed exist. P01 is an optional character. What I need is only '**' without P01

Comment: Yes but what is the rule? When P01 is optional character and when part of the result? Your rule is not clear that's why you cannot write the regex

Comment: What I need is the characters before '-2I_114.dexl.gz' or before '_P01-2I_114.dexl.gz'

Comment: see my answer below. I got the expected result

Comment: yeah. the result is what I expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/rSg2Y6/1/):

```
gb_(reg|bk)_test\d
```

Comment: will this pattern be much more general. If the example is aa_bb_ccc-2I_114.dexl.gz, aa_dd_P01-2I_114.dexl.gz

Answer (score 2):

A problem with your question is that the rules for expected results are not clear. You state that `**-2I_114.dexl.gz` is a matching pattern and ** can be anything. In this case for the example:

`gb_bk_test1_P01-2I_114.dexl.gz`  we can have two valid results:

gb_bk_test1 AND gb_bk_test1_P01 - you need to define a rule that can decide which one is the correct one. From your post if we assume that the rule is NOT having _P01 (as a hard coded string because we don't know anything else for the task). Then a regext that would work for you is that one:

```
(\w*?)(_P01|)-2I_114.dexl.gz -> Group 1 here is the string you want
```

Also here you can modify the second part to add additional patterns excluded from the general one - like (_P01|_P06|) or (_P\d+|) or whatever you need

A working example can be seen here: 
[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/rSg2Y6/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^| )([^ -]*?(_P01)?)(?=-)
```

is the most general pattern i can think of
it matches

1. **gb_reg_test2**-2I_114.dexl.gz, **gb_bk_test1**_P01-2I_114.dexl.gz
2. **aa_aSD_asdsa**-qwwe.ddf_sdfsdf_asdf-as
3. **123_3d3_22**-adsfasdf.gz
4. **aA1?~²³²**-23423
5. **asdfas_sdfsd**_P01-sadfdefwe.gz

Explanation:

1. `(?:^| )`: Beginning of the line or leading whitespace
2. `[^ -]*?`: Any character but ' ' or '-' matched as least times as possible
3. `(_P01)?` "_P01" as optional element, match if existing
4. `(?=-)`: Directly followed by `-`

The item you want is the first captured group

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w*?)(_P\d+|)-\d+I_\d+.dexl.gz
```

It has been resolved. Thanks for Veselin Davidov's answer. And thanks for everyone's help. Really appreciate it.